# How can I find <img src> nested within <div> using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

New to both Python and Beautiful Soup. I am trying to collect the `src` of an `img` inserted into a collapsible section on an e-commerce site. The collapsible sections that contain the images have the class of `accordion__contents`, but `<img>` inserted into the collapsible sections do not have a specific `class`. Not every page contains an image; some contain multiple.

I am trying to extract the `src` from `img` that are randomly nested within `<div>`. In the HTML example below, my desired output would be: `<[https://example.com/image1.png]>`

```
<div class="accordion__title">Description</div>    
<div class="accordion__contents">
       <p>Enjoy Daiya’s Hon’y Mustard Dressing on your salads</p>
    </div>
<div class="accordion__title">Ingredients</div>     
<div class="accordion__contents">
       <p>Non-GMO Expeller Pressed Canola Oil, Filtered Water</p>
       <p><strong>CONTAINS: MUSTARD</strong></p>
    </div>
<div class="accordion__title">Nutrition</div>     
<div class="accordion__contents">
       <p>
         <img alt="" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-57054" height="300" src="https://example.com/image1.png" width="162"/>
       </p>
    </div>
<div class="accordion__title">Warnings</div>     
<div class="accordion__contents">
       <p><strong>Contains mustard</strong></p>
    </div>
```

I've written the following code that successfully drills down to the full  tag, but I can't figure out how to extract `src` once I'm there.

```
  img_href = container.find_all(class_ ='accordion__contents') # generates the output above, in a list form
  img_href = [img.find_all('img') for img in img_href]  
  for x in img_href:
    if len(x)==0: # skip over empty items in the list that don't have images
      continue
    else:
      print(x) # print to make sure the image is there
      x.find('img')[`src`] # generates error - see below
```

The error I am getting is `ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?` My intent is *not* to be treating a list like an item, thus the loop.
I've tried `find_all()` combined with `.attrs('src')` but that also didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

I've simplified my example, but the URL for the page I'm scraping is [here](https://gtfoitsvegan.com/product/hony-mustard-dressing-by-daiya/?v=7516fd43adaa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `".accordion__contents img"`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://gtfoitsvegan.com/product/hony-mustard-dressing-by-daiya/?v=7516fd43adaa"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_imgs = [img["src"] for img in soup.select(".accordion__contents img")]
print(all_imgs)
```

Prints:

```py
['https://gtfoitsvegan.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Daiya-Honey-Mustard-Nutrition-Facts-162x300.png']
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Follow-up question: do you have any suggestions on how to find the preceding `div` with the class `accordion__title` for the purpose of labeling the image types in a data table? I'd initially structured as a loop for that reason - i.e. so I could associate `Nutrition` in position `[3]` in the list with the URL.

Comment: @roody look at `.find_previous()`/`.find_parent()` functions. [Doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous)